# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cycle detected in DAG. Faulty task

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

i am running the airflow pipeline but codes looks seems good but actually i'm getting the airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cycle detected in DAG. Faulty task: 
can u please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 27):

This can happen due to duplicate task_id'a in multiple tasks.

Answer (score 7):

Without the code, it's kind of hard to help you. However, this means that you have a loop in your DAG. Generally, thie error happens when one of your task has a downstream task whose own downstream chain includes it again (A calls B calls C calls D calls A again, for example). 
That's not permitted by Airflow (and DAGs in general).

Answer (score 0):

On top of the two flags mentioned above, this could also be due to a newly added task that has a trigger rule associated to it (maybe even refers an upstream task using .output)

Examples that could lead to airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cycle detected in DAG:
trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE or
TASK_MAP[EMR_SERVERLESS_APP_TASK].output