# Airflow repeat one taske in a dag

Tags: airflow

I just began to use apach airflow. it's a great tool but I have no idea how to do a work like this case:
I need to do tasks repeatly like this, modify the channel word and build the codes and do it again:
set_channel_a >> build_src >> set_channel_b >> build_src

but airflow raise an error that there is cycle in flow and can not do it.

I have to change to set_channel_a >> build_src_a >> set_channel_b >> build_src_b

but the build_src_a & build_src_b are exactly same. I don't like duplicate codes.

what is the correct way to handle this kind of case?

Comment: Could you post your dag file?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is based on DAGs (Directed Acyclic Graphs), so you cannot have loops or cycles in your code.

[airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cycle detected in DAG. Faulty task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731858/airflow-exceptions-airflowexception-cycle-detected-in-dag-faulty-task)